# Run-Time Check Failure #0. Lost as to how to use CDECL

Tags: c++, assembly

I've been asked with changing some __asm code so that it implements a C++ calling convention. I've tried using cdecl but I keep getting this error

> Run-Time Check Failure #0: The value of ESP was not properly saved across a function call. This is usually a result of calling a function declared with one calling convention with a function pointer declared with a different calling convention.

The code is used to encrypt a string one character at a time using a for loop. The function `encrypt_1` encodes the character that is passing through the for loop at the time.

I've attempted to use cdecl by assigning different values to the base pointer (`ebp`) and the stack pointer (`esp`) for both the for loop and the function but I'm continuously getting Run-Time Check Failure #0, and every attempt I've made to tweak it results in the program breaking. I've been stressing over this for a couple of days, can anybody give me a hint as to where I may be going wrong?

The Body:

```
void encrypt_chars (int length, char EKey)
{
  char temp_char;                       // Character temporary store

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)      // Encrypt characters one at a time
  {
    temp_char = OChars[i];              // Get the next char from Original Chars array
                                        // Each character in the string will be encrypted individually
    __asm
    {                                   //
      push   eax                        // Stores a backup of the location of eax to be used later
      push   ecx                        // Stores a backup of the charcter to be encrypted in the stack for later use
      push   edx                        // Stores a backup of the location for the encrypted character in the stack for later use

                                        //
      movzx  ecx, temp_char             // Places the character (8 bits) to be encrypted in the ecx register (32 bits) and replaces any extraneous bits with 0 as they are not being used. 
      lea    eax, EKey                  // places the Ekey in the eax register for later use. Registers are fast than calling variables?

      push   ebp
      mov    ebp, esp
     // sub    esp, 4

      push ecx                          // Parameter for encrypt1. - Temporary Character
      push eax                          // Parameter for encrypt1. - Address for the key.

      call   encrypt_1                  // Begins the Encryption Function                   
      mov    temp_char, dl              // Stores the encrypted character in the temp_char variable to be reconstruced later

      add esp, 8

      pop eax                           // Restoring eax to previous location before parameter call                             
      pop ecx                           // Restores Temporary Character location before parameter call


      pop    edx                        // Restores the edx register to its original value, ready for the next character
      pop    ecx                        // Restores the ecx register to its original value, ready for the next character
      pop    eax                        // Restores the eax register to its original value, ready for the next character
      mov esp, ebp
      pop ebp
    //    ret
    }
    EChars[i] = temp_char;              // Store encrypted char in the Encrypted Chars array
  }
  return;
```

The Function:

```
  __asm
  {
  encrypt_1:
      push ebp                              //Saves the present value of ebp on the stack for later use
          mov ebp, esp                      //Places the stack pointer where the base pointer is so variables can be stored
          mov ecx, [ebp +08h]
          mov edx, [ebp +0Ch]
      push  ecx                             // Stores the original character on the top of the stack
          movzx ecx, byte ptr[eax]          // Moves the Ekey (8-bit) into the ecx register (32-bit), changing all extraneous bits to 0 so it can be rotated
          add   cl, 0x01                    // Adds 1 to Ekey
          rol   cl, 1                       // Rotates the binary value of Ekey to the left 6 times for further security
          rol   cl, 1                       // Could have just used "rol  cl, 6"
          rol   cl, 1
          rol   cl, 1
          rol   cl, 1
          rol   cl, 1
          mov   edx, ecx                    // Move the encrypted Ekey to edx, freeing the ecx register for the original character to be used later.
          mov   byte ptr[eax], dl           // Move byte pointer to the left side of eax
          pop   ecx                         // Retrieves the original character to be encrypted
     x1 : rol   cl, 1                       // Rotate the original character one place to the left , encrypting it
          dec   edx                         // Decrease the rotated Ekey by one, acting as a counter to continue decrypting the original character
          jnz   x1                          // Jump back to x1 unless the Ekey = 0, which dictates that the encryption is complete
          add   ecx, 0x20                   // Add 32 bits to the encrypted character, filling the register
          mov   edx, ecx                    // Place the encrypted character in the edx register, ready to be returned
          mov   esp, ebp
          pop   ebp
          //add esp, 8
          ret                               // Return the encrypted character
  }

  //--- End of Assembly code
}
```

PS. Sorry for some of the messy commented out lines, I've been trying various things trying to get it to work.

Comment: Why are you writing the calling code in assembly? Just write the call in C++ and use a standard calling convention. Or inline the whole thing. The code you’ve written to make the call is about 10x too complicated.

Comment: x86 has multi-count rotate.  You could `rol cl, 6` with the same performance as `rol cl,1`.  Actually better performance on Intel; the implicit-1 short form produces more flag outputs and thus costs 2 uops.

Comment: The assembly in `encrypt_chars` is a mess with many problems.  You can start fixing them by _not_ changing `ebp`, restoring registers in the same order you save them, and studying the calling conventions you're trying to use.  (Looking at code generated by the compiler can help.)

Comment: Write it in C++. Compile to assembly. Look at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no reason to write the call in assembly. You should change the calling code to:

```
    EChars[i] = encrypt_1(&EKey, OChars[i]);
```

If for some reason you feel that you *must* write it in assembly, then you could write:

```
    temp_char = OChars[i];
    __asm
    {
      movzx  ecx, temp_char
      lea    eax, EKey
      push ecx               // Second param: character to encrypt
      push eax               // First param: address of EKey.
      call encrypt_1
      mov temp_char, al
    }
    EChars[i] = temp_char;
```

The Function:

```
  __asm
  {
  encrypt_1:
      push  ebp
      mov   ebp, esp
      mov   eax, [ebp+08h]       // first param: address of EKey
      mov   dl, [ebp+0Ch]        // second param: character to encrypt
      mov   cl, byte ptr [eax]   // get value of EKey
      add   cl, 0x01
      rol   cl, 6
      mov   byte ptr [eax], cl   // store updated value of EKey
      rol   dl, cl
      add   dl, 0x20
      movzx eax, dl              // Return encrypted character in eax
      mov   esp, ebp
      pop   ebp
      ret
  }
```

Other than simplification, the only things that I fixed were:
1. Use of eax without loading it within the function.
2. Reversed order of the function parameters.
3. The EKey parameter to the function wasn't used at all.

Comment: And of course further optimization is possible using a variable-count rotate instead of a loop, changing register allocation so the count is in CL instead of AL.  If `al` is zero on the first iteration, the loop runs 256 times, which is the same as a rotate count of zero.  But you still want the `movzx` at the end to be between different registers (so mov-elimination works), so probably EAX for the pointer.

Comment: @Peter, is `movzx eax, al` really slower than `movzx eax, dl`? I never would have guessed.

Comment: Yeah, 1 cycle latency vs. zero.  [Can x86's MOV really be "free"? Why can't I reproduce this at all?](//stackoverflow.com/q/44169342).  (Similarly, zero-extending from 32 to 64 with `mov edi,edi` is worse than `mov eax,edi` on Intel IvB+ *and* AMD Ryzen, which also does integer mov-elimination but not for movzx, just mov)